# Identificar y remover letras de una columna en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT NUM_USUARIO FROM USUARIOS
```

La columna `NUM_USUARIO` es tipo `String`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que hacer un `JOIN` con otra tabla en la cual los usuarios no tienen letras solo números.

Me podrían decir como detectar si existe una letra en un registro y borrar esa letra solo dejando los números.

Comment: La letra está siempre en la primera posición?

Comment: La letra siempre se encuentra al inicio

Comment: y en la otra tabla son números guardados como string o como tipo de datos numérico?. Por ejemplo, es `'0136875'` o `136875`?

Comment: Son números guardados como String '0136875'

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta con substring, solo remueve el primer caracter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varias alternativas para resolver tú problema.

Si siempre comienza con una letra podrias quitarla con un `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('A3845206',2,LEN('A3845206'))
```

Si deseas validar que el registro sea númerico

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('A3845206')
```

Si deseas conocer la posición del primer registro númerico

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 'A3845206')
```

Espero alguna de ellas te sirva.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tablaA') is not null
drop table tablaA;
go
if object_id ('tablaB') is not null
drop table tablaB;
go
create table tablaA(id int identity(1,1), valorA varchar(5));
create table tablaB(id varchar(2), valorA varchar(5));
insert tablaA(valorA)values('A');
insert tablaA(valorA)values('B');
insert tablaA(valorA)values('C');
insert tablaA(valorA)values('D');
insert tablaA(valorA)values('E');
insert tablaB(id, valorA)values('A1','A');
insert tablaB(id, valorA)values('A2','B');
insert tablaB(id, valorA)values('A3','C');
insert tablaB(id, valorA)values('A4','D');
insert tablaB(id, valorA)values('A5','E');

select *
from tablaA a
inner join tablaB b
on a.id = SUBSTRING(b.id, 2, len(b.id))
```